# How print string

Tags: linux, shell

How to write a text on the shell terminal?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

print "hello"
```

I got this error

```
-bash: print: command not found
```

Cordialy

Comment: https://devhints.io/bash - Try `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is: `echo string`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to display, Bash has either the `echo` or `printf` commands. The differences are described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819), the main point being to use `printf` for anything uncontrolled.